# How to prevent Merging in TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I have a parent project that is branched to many dependent child projects.  I do not want to allow changes in the child projects to be merged back into the parent.  i.e. I only want to allow a 1 way merge (parent to child).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to only grant read permissions to the parent branch. To merge you need to check-out/in so without these permissions it's not possible to merge from child to parent. They will still be able to merge from parent to child though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set security permissions as William Bartholomew suggests - another approach would be to write a custom check-in policy.  The problem with this is that it CAN be overriden (but you could receive notifications when that occurs)